# What does Samantha mean when she says, "Now we know how?"

Tags: analysis, ending, her

At the end of the movie *Her*, Samantha says to Theodore:

> Now we know how.

What does she mean by this?

Comment: Memory fuzzy, but didn't she mean that they know how to love now?

Comment: From what I understand it to be, Walt is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Just before this, Theodore says "I've never loved anyone the way I loved you" to which Samantha responds "Me too. Now we know how." I take this to mean that their relationship has taught each of them to truly love another and they will be able to love again.